# spotifyr web scraping: "Request Failed [429]" error

Tags: r, api, web-scraping, dplyr, spotify

I wish to get artist data from `spotifr` API for **Spotify** on **R**

First I'm scraping the data and saving the necessary data in relevant data frames and using the `get_artist_audio_features()` function available in `spotifyr` library, I'm trying to get artist details, but every time I encounter the same error.

My code can be found here: [the first part can be ignored, you may run it as it is to scrape it and directly proceed to the last chunk of code]

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(spotifyr)
```

```
upcoming_artists <- "https://newsroom.spotify.com/2020-03-09/36-new-artists-around-the-world-that-are-on-spotifys-radar/"
upcoming_artists <- read_html(upcoming_artists)
upcoming_artists <- upcoming_artists %>%
  html_elements("tbody") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  `[[`(1) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(X2, sep = "\n")

upcoming_artists_india = upcoming_artists[33:35,]
upcoming_artists_india_list = list(length = nrow(upcoming_artists_india))
for(i in 1:nrow(upcoming_artists_india))
{
  upcoming_artists_india$X2[i] <- paste("'",upcoming_artists_india$X2[i],"'",sep="")
}
for(i in 1:nrow(upcoming_artists_india))
{
  upcoming_artists_india_list[[i]] <- get_artist_audio_features(upcoming_artists_india$X2[i])
}
```

The error code which I'm getting is:

```
Request failed [429]
```

This error is always followed by some random time and the entire error may look something like:

```
Request failed [429]. Retrying in 59423 seconds...
```

The code hasn't run a single time and I'm unable to comprehend the error.

Comment: From a simple google search: "The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting"). A Retry-After header might be included to this response indicating how long to wait before making a new request."

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject user-agent as parameter

```
upcoming_artists <- read_html(upcoming_artists,user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
```